# Angular: How to make my component modify the value of one of its parent's properties

Tags: angular, angular-components, kendo-ui-angular2

I have been working with Kendo for Angular for a while and there's something that intrigues me. There are many Kendo components that have a property called `value`. This property is connected to a property of my component (the parent) like this:

```
<kendo-numerictextbox [value]="quantity">
</kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Here, `quantity` is a property of my component. The interesting part is that everytime the user clicks on the numeric text box, the Kendo component updates the property of my component. I was trying to replicate the same behavior with my components, concretely, I was experimenting with `@HostBinding` but instead of being used with a directive, I use it with a component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @HostBinding('title') title;

  constructor() { }    
}
```

Another thing I tried was injecting the parent to the child:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(@Host() public parent: AppComponent) { }
}
```

In this case, yes, I have access to the parent properties, but it implies that the child component has to know its parent's type.

Here's a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6qfpyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts) to stackblitz.

Honestly, I have no idea about how to do it. Any idea?

**EDIT:** Please, notice that what I'm asking about is how I can replicate the same behavior Kendo components have about their `value` property. I'm not asking for a workaround using shared services.

Comment: Dosen't event emiting do the job, for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) should be what you are looking for.

You first need an `@Input()` which will take the current value from the parent.
Additionally you need an `@Output()` which will emit the new value.

For Example

parent.html

```
<kendo-numerictextbox [(value)]="quantity">
</kendo-numerictextbox>
```

child.ts

```
@Input() value: string;
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmiter<string> = new EventEmiter<string>();

public someEvent(newString: string) {
 this.valueChange.emit(newString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `BehaviorSubject` to achieve that (or eventEmitter aswell). I used the first.

Add a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
    private $change = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
    closeEvent = this.$change.asObservable();

    public changeText(){
      this.$change.next("Child changed title");
    }
}
```

child component:

```
import { Component, Host, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @HostBinding('title') title;

  constructor(@Host() public parent: AppComponent, private serivce: AppService) { }
  public magic(){
    this.serivce.changeText();
  }
}
```

parent component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService} from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'Title from parent';

  constructor(private service: AppService){
    this.service.closeEvent
    .subscribe( evt => {
      if(!!evt){
        this.title = evt;
      }
    })
  }
}

app module

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ChildComponent ],
  providers: [AppService],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When you click on "Click me" the text change from a change fired from your child component